# using CruiseControl.Net and SVN

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to use cruisecontrol.net to check a svn repositry for an update and then exports the updated project. I am new to cruisecontrol and not sure how to do this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this does not help...but take a look a Scott Cowan's blog. He has a good process with CruiseControl.NET and SVN. You might find what you are looking for in there.

http://sleepoverrated.com/archive/2007/12/buildknowledgepromotingyourbuild/

I also made the same post on this stackoverflow question:

[Setting up SVN to Best Suit Dev -> QA -> Prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616254/setting-up-svn-to-best-suit-dev-qa-prod/616357#616357)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to set up CruiseControl to check for an update and pull down the code into your local repository

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Subversion+Source+Control+Block

Then, what I would do if you want to export is use the executable task

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task

to call the svn executable and pass it the export flag and parameters you need.